# Blackberry:How can I slide a bitmap image on my screen to show the next/other image? Some kind of animation?

Tags: blackberry

I need to display some images. And I want to slide out one image from one slide of the screen so the the next image is displayed.
Is it possible to have such an animation?
thanks

Comment: hi Bohemian.. can you post the code for some help. Actually I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it with a timer which can keep on feeding new values to the x or y coordinates of the bitmap. That way we show it moving horizontally, vertically or diagonally.
Any more ideas??

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not useful to you yet, but device software 5 has features for doing just that.
(PictureScrollField)